# If there's a delay caused by a background check and the start date needs to be pushed back, should a new contract or contract amendment be signed?

Tags: job-offer, new-job, background-check, consulting

I told them I need to give my current employer a notice period of three weeks. Then I received an offer letter with a start date which respects that. The offer letter says it is  subject to background checks. I signed the offer letter.

I am talking about a consulting agreement.

If there's a delay caused by a background check and the start date needs to be pushed back, should a new contract or contract amendment be signed including the new start date after I receive a note from HR telling me I am clear?

Comment: This question seems related: [Pushing start date back depending on background check](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/68048/pushing-start-date-back-depending-on-background-check)

Comment: @toolic Thanks for commenting. Yes, it's related but it does not answer my question (whether or not a new contract or contract amendment should be signed)

Comment: Does the contract explicitly include the start date? I don't think mine did.

Comment: @keshlam Yes, the contract indicates the date the work will commence

Comment: It really depends on the exact type of work, but it's also possible that employment can commence, while the background check is ongoing. If it is rare for background checks to fail, this may be preferable to delaying the start of employment.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Fintech (they are launching a bank), software development.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie  Does it make sense to push back start date?

Comment: @jesolit884 It's impossible for me to say. There may be regulatory reasons that mandate it. But if you've agreed to it, you've agreed to it.

Answer (score 4):

> If there's a delay caused by a background check and the start date
> needs to be pushed back, should a new contract or contract amendment
> be signed including the new start date after I receive a note from HR
> telling me I am clear?

You have a contract offer with a contingency, the background check.

When that contingency is removed, they should send you a new offer letter with no contingency, and possibly a new start date. If the background check is done quickly, then there may be no need to update the start date, but there should be a new date if the three week notice period would take you beyond the original estimated start date.

I would expect a new updated offer letter as each contingency is removed.

> I told them I need to give my current employer a notice period of
> three weeks.

I wouldn't give notice until I received in writing that all contingencies have been removed, and have returned the signed updated offer letter.

Comment: I am not aware of companies that re-send employment contracts to be re-signed once background checks are complete.

Comment: I have had this done with me personally several times. It has also been done with one of my children. I also know that when the company I currently work for makes an offer there are always contingencies: background, customer approval, and sometimes the awarding a of a new customer contract. As these contingencies are removed a new offer letter is generated.

Comment: Are you sure the initial documents you received were not letters of intent or something like that? Where I am, contracts are pretty serious, and having multiple contracts that overlap each other can create ambiguity and inconsistency, which is problematic in court.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep So after contingencies are removed, a new offer letter is generated and that new offer letter should not mention any contingencies. Right?

Comment: @jesolit884, that is what I expect and have observed. You want in writing that everything is good to go, so you can tell your current employer that you will be leaving.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep Thanks. If the background check is completed fast and I have enough time to give notice period of three weeks, there's no need to sign a new offer letter with no contingency because start date would not be pushed back, right?

Comment: @jesolit884 If the original paperwork said the offer was contingent on passing a background check, you want them to update the agreement to remove that contingency when they have determined you passed. Otherwise how would you know you can tell your current employer. I would expect an updated offer letter even if the check only took one day.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep Thanks again. HR told me they would send me a note telling me I am clear as soon as I pass the background check. I guess that will let me tell my current employer. You think that's not enough and a new updated consulting agreement should be signed?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've already agreed that your employment can only commence once your background check is complete. Given that, it seems they are able to delay your employment while the background check process is ongoing.

There is no need for a subsequent agreement.